# How to sample data points for two variables that has highest (close to +1) or lowest (close to zero) correlation coefficient?

Tags: python, r, matlab, random, statistics

Let's assume that we have `N` (`N=212` in this case) number of datapoints for both variables `A` and `B`. I have to sample `n` (`n=50` in this case) number of data points for A and B such that A and B should have the `highest possible positive correlation coefficient` or `lowest correlation coefficient (close to zero)`  for that sample set. Is there any easy way to do this (Please note that the sampling should be index-based i.e., if we select a i<sup>th</sup> datapoint then both A and B should be taken corresponding to that i<sup>th</sup> index)? Below is the sample dataframe (Coded in R but I am OK with any programming language):

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1.37, 1.44, 1.51, 1.59, 1.67, 1.75, 1.82,1.9, 1.97, 2.05, 2.12, 2.19, 2.26, 2.33, 2.4, 2.47, 2.53, 2.6,  2.66, 2.72, 2.78, 2.84, 2.9, 2.95, 3.01, 3.05, 3.09, 3.13, 3.16,  3.18, 3.2, 3.21, 3.22, 3.22, 3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 3.22, 3.21, 3.2,  3.18, 3.15, 3.13, 3.1, 3.06, 3.03, 3, 2.98, 2.95, 2.92, 2.89,  2.86, 2.84, 2.81, 2.79, 2.76, 2.74, 2.71, 2.69, 2.67, 2.65, 2.62,  2.6, 2.58, 2.56, 2.55, 2.54, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.54, 2.55, 2.56, 2.58, 2.59, 2.61, 2.62, 2.64, 2.66, 2.68, 2.7, 2.72, 2.74, 2.76, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 2.88, 2.91, 2.94, 2.98, 3.02, 3.06, 3.1, 3.14, 3.19, 3.24, 3.29, 3.34, 3.39, 3.45, 3.5, 3.56, 3.61, 3.66, 3.71, 3.77, 3.82, 3.87, 3.91, 3.96, 4.01, 4.06, 4.11, 4.15, 4.2, 4.24, 4.28, 4.32, 4.35, 4.39, 4.42, 4.44, 4.47, 4.49, 4.51, 4.53, 4.54, 4.56, 4.57, 4.58, 4.59, 4.6, 4.61, 4.62, 4.63, 4.64, 4.65, 4.65, 4.66, 4.66, 4.66, 4.66, 4.65, 4.64, 4.63, 4.62, 4.61, 4.6, 4.58, 4.56, 4.54, 4.52, 4.5, 4.48, 4.45, 4.42, 4.39, 4.36, 4.32, 4.28, 4.23, 4.19, 4.14, 4.08, 4.03, 3.97, 3.91, 3.84, 3.78, 3.71, 3.64, 3.57, 3.5, 3.43, 3.36, 3.29, 3.22, 3.15, 3.08, 3, 2.93, 2.86, 2.78, 2.7, 2.63, 2.55, 2.47, 2.4, 2.32, 2.24, 2.16, 2.08, 2, 1.93, 1.85, 1.76, 1.68, 1.6, 1.53, 1.45, 1.38, 1.31, 1.24, 1.18, 1.11, 1.05, 0.99, 0.93, 0.88, 0.83, 0.78), B = c(1.44, 0.76, 0.43, 0.26, 0.69, 0.46, 0.07, 0.22, 0.38, 0.44, 0.37, 0.31, 0.48, 0.45, 0.86, 1.15, 1.13, 0.5, 0.39, 0.64, 0.71, 0.86, 0.45, 0.6, 0.29, 0.58, 0.24, 0.64, 0.61, 0.49, 0.53, 0.27, 0.03, 0.18, 0.25, 0.24, 0.2, 0.23, 0.3, 0.39, 0.32, 0.22, 0.18, 0.24, 0.2, 0.61, 0.12, 0.16, 0.29, 0.51, 0.48, 0.27, 0.28, 0.41, 0.48, 0.76, 0.45, 0.59, 0.55, 0.69, 0.46, 0.42, 0.42, 0.22, 0.34, 0.19, 0.11, 0.18, 0.33, 0.48, 0.91, 1.1, 0.32, 0.18, 0.09, NaN, 0.27, 0.31, 0.3, 0.27, 0.79, 0.43, 0.32, 0.48, 0.77, 0.32, 0.28, 0.4, 0.46, 0.69, 0.93, 0.71, 0.41, 0.3, 0.34, 0.44, 0.3, 1.03, 0.97, 0.35, 0.51, 1.21, 1.58, 0.67, 0.37, 0.04, 0.57, 0.67, 0.7, 0.47, 0.48, 0.38, 0.61, 0.8, 1.1, 0.39, 0.38, 0.48, 0.58, 0.55, 0.7, 0.7, 0.86, 0.61, 0.18, 0.9, 0.83, 0.9, 0.83, 0.61, 0.23, 0.22, 0.44, 0.41, 0.52, 0.71, 0.59, 0.9, 1.23, 1.56, 0.73, 0.69, 1.23, 1.28, 0.43, 0.97, 0.58, 0.44, 0.23, 0.46, 0.48, 0.22, 0.21, 0.66, 0.26, 0.55, 0.69, 0.84, 1.04, 0.83, 0.85, 0.63, 0.63, 0.17, 0.58, 0.66, 0.44, 0.53, 0.81, 0.63, 0.51, 0.15, 0.42, 0.77, 0.73, 0.87, 0.34, 0.51, 0.63, 0.05, 0.23, 0.87, 0.84, 0.39, 0.61, 0.89, 1.06, 1.08, 1.01, 1.05, 0.27, 0.79, 0.88, 1.34, 1.26, 1.42, 0.81, 1.46, 0.84, 0.54, 0.95, 1.42, 0.44, 0.73, 1.31, 1.75, 2.1, 2.36, 1.94, 2.31, 2.17, 2.35)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -212L))
```

Comment: “Highest”, or largest magnitude?  Correlation can be negative.

Comment: @pjs - You are right. Correlation can be negative. I meant largest in positive side. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better way, but it seems to me that this is something that could be solved with a genetic algorithm. The following approach will return the correlation value (i.e. fitness) only if n genes/variables are "turned on"; otherwise, zero is returned.

I had to initialize the population with individuals with exactly 50 genes turned on to start the evolutionary process. The result is pretty high (r = 0.97) after 1142 generations, and no improvement is made over the last 50 generations.

```
# required libraries
library(GA)
library(memoise)

# original data
df <- structure(list(A = c(1.37, 1.44, 1.51, 1.59, 1.67, 1.75, 1.82,1.9, 1.97, 2.05, 2.12, 2.19, 2.26, 2.33, 2.4, 2.47, 2.53, 2.6,  2.66, 2.72, 2.78, 2.84, 2.9, 2.95, 3.01, 3.05, 3.09, 3.13, 3.16,  3.18, 3.2, 3.21, 3.22, 3.22, 3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 3.22, 3.21, 3.2,  3.18, 3.15, 3.13, 3.1, 3.06, 3.03, 3, 2.98, 2.95, 2.92, 2.89,  2.86, 2.84, 2.81, 2.79, 2.76, 2.74, 2.71, 2.69, 2.67, 2.65, 2.62,  2.6, 2.58, 2.56, 2.55, 2.54, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.54, 2.55, 2.56, 2.58, 2.59, 2.61, 2.62, 2.64, 2.66, 2.68, 2.7, 2.72, 2.74, 2.76, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 2.88, 2.91, 2.94, 2.98, 3.02, 3.06, 3.1, 3.14, 3.19, 3.24, 3.29, 3.34, 3.39, 3.45, 3.5, 3.56, 3.61, 3.66, 3.71, 3.77, 3.82, 3.87, 3.91, 3.96, 4.01, 4.06, 4.11, 4.15, 4.2, 4.24, 4.28, 4.32, 4.35, 4.39, 4.42, 4.44, 4.47, 4.49, 4.51, 4.53, 4.54, 4.56, 4.57, 4.58, 4.59, 4.6, 4.61, 4.62, 4.63, 4.64, 4.65, 4.65, 4.66, 4.66, 4.66, 4.66, 4.65, 4.64, 4.63, 4.62, 4.61, 4.6, 4.58, 4.56, 4.54, 4.52, 4.5, 4.48, 4.45, 4.42, 4.39, 4.36, 4.32, 4.28, 4.23, 4.19, 4.14, 4.08, 4.03, 3.97, 3.91, 3.84, 3.78, 3.71, 3.64, 3.57, 3.5, 3.43, 3.36, 3.29, 3.22, 3.15, 3.08, 3, 2.93, 2.86, 2.78, 2.7, 2.63, 2.55, 2.47, 2.4, 2.32, 2.24, 2.16, 2.08, 2, 1.93, 1.85, 1.76, 1.68, 1.6, 1.53, 1.45, 1.38, 1.31, 1.24, 1.18, 1.11, 1.05, 0.99, 0.93, 0.88, 0.83, 0.78), B = c(1.44, 0.76, 0.43, 0.26, 0.69, 0.46, 0.07, 0.22, 0.38, 0.44, 0.37, 0.31, 0.48, 0.45, 0.86, 1.15, 1.13, 0.5, 0.39, 0.64, 0.71, 0.86, 0.45, 0.6, 0.29, 0.58, 0.24, 0.64, 0.61, 0.49, 0.53, 0.27, 0.03, 0.18, 0.25, 0.24, 0.2, 0.23, 0.3, 0.39, 0.32, 0.22, 0.18, 0.24, 0.2, 0.61, 0.12, 0.16, 0.29, 0.51, 0.48, 0.27, 0.28, 0.41, 0.48, 0.76, 0.45, 0.59, 0.55, 0.69, 0.46, 0.42, 0.42, 0.22, 0.34, 0.19, 0.11, 0.18, 0.33, 0.48, 0.91, 1.1, 0.32, 0.18, 0.09, NaN, 0.27, 0.31, 0.3, 0.27, 0.79, 0.43, 0.32, 0.48, 0.77, 0.32, 0.28, 0.4, 0.46, 0.69, 0.93, 0.71, 0.41, 0.3, 0.34, 0.44, 0.3, 1.03, 0.97, 0.35, 0.51, 1.21, 1.58, 0.67, 0.37, 0.04, 0.57, 0.67, 0.7, 0.47, 0.48, 0.38, 0.61, 0.8, 1.1, 0.39, 0.38, 0.48, 0.58, 0.55, 0.7, 0.7, 0.86, 0.61, 0.18, 0.9, 0.83, 0.9, 0.83, 0.61, 0.23, 0.22, 0.44, 0.41, 0.52, 0.71, 0.59, 0.9, 1.23, 1.56, 0.73, 0.69, 1.23, 1.28, 0.43, 0.97, 0.58, 0.44, 0.23, 0.46, 0.48, 0.22, 0.21, 0.66, 0.26, 0.55, 0.69, 0.84, 1.04, 0.83, 0.85, 0.63, 0.63, 0.17, 0.58, 0.66, 0.44, 0.53, 0.81, 0.63, 0.51, 0.15, 0.42, 0.77, 0.73, 0.87, 0.34, 0.51, 0.63, 0.05, 0.23, 0.87, 0.84, 0.39, 0.61, 0.89, 1.06, 1.08, 1.01, 1.05, 0.27, 0.79, 0.88, 1.34, 1.26, 1.42, 0.81, 1.46, 0.84, 0.54, 0.95, 1.42, 0.44, 0.73, 1.31, 1.75, 2.1, 2.36, 1.94, 2.31, 2.17, 2.35)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -212L))

# fitness function
fitfun <- function(x, data, n){
  if(sum(x) == n){ # only calculate correlation if n genes/variable are included
    incl <- which(x == 1)
    res <- unname(cor.test(x = df[incl,"A"], y = df[incl,"B"], method = "pearson")$estimate)
  }else{
    res <- 0 # otherwise return zero fitness
  }
  return(res)
}

# set-up initial population
popSize = 200 # population size
set.seed(1)
initPop <- matrix(0, nrow = popSize, ncol = nrow(df))
for(i in seq(nrow(initPop))){
  initPop[i,sample(x = nrow(df), size = 50)] <- 1
}  
rowSums(initPop)    

# Run genetic algorithm
fitfun <- memoise::memoise(f = fitfun) # use memoisation to record unique genetic solutions (may help with speed)
fit <- ga(type = "binary", nBits = nrow(df), fitness = fitfun, data = df, 
  n = 50, popSize = popSize, maxiter = 1500, run = 200, seed = 1112,
  pmutation = 0.2, elitism = popSize*0.2,
  suggestions = initPop)
memoise::forget(f = fitfun)

# Result and plot
(incl <- which(fit@solution == 1)) # selected rows of df
fit@fitnessValue ; cor.test(x = df[incl,"A"], y = df[incl,"B"], method = "pearson")$estimate # double check (same)
plot(fit)
```

[image]

As per your comment on how to adjust the fitness function to target a specific correlation, see the example below. Since `ga` always maximizes fitness, you will need to flip the sign of the output (e.g. `-sqrt((res-targ)^2)` is the squared error to the target value).

```
# fitness function - correlation closest to target value
fitfun0 <- function(x, data, n, targ){
  if(sum(x) == n){ # only calculate correlation if n genes/variable are included
    incl <- which(x == 1)
    res <- unname(cor.test(x = df[incl,"A"], y = df[incl,"B"], method = "pearson")$estimate)
    res <- res 
  }else{
    res <- 100
  }
  res <- -sqrt((res-targ)^2) # reverse sign since fitness is maximized
  return(res)
}

# set-up initial population
popSize = 200 # population size
set.seed(1)
initPop <- matrix(0, nrow = popSize, ncol = nrow(df))
for(i in seq(nrow(initPop))){
  initPop[i,sample(x = nrow(df), size = 50)] <- 1
}  
rowSums(initPop)    

# Run genetic algorithm
fitfun0 <- memoise::memoise(f = fitfun0) # use memoisation to record unique genetic solutions (may help with speed)
fit <- ga(type = "binary", nBits = nrow(df), fitness = fitfun0, data = df, targ = -0.1,
  n = 50, popSize = popSize, maxiter = 1500, run = 200, seed = 1112,
  pmutation = 0.2, elitism = popSize*0.2,
  suggestions = initPop)
memoise::forget(f = fitfun0)

# Result and plot
(incl <- which(fit@solution == 1)) # selected rows of df
cor.test(x = df[incl,"A"], y = df[incl,"B"], method = "pearson")$estimate # close to target
plot(fit)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, how to decide initial population size? Is it some sort of hyperparameter in GA? Also, how to modify the fitness function if one wants to get the sample corresponding to lowest correlation coefficient (close to zero)?

Comment: @raghav - Glad it helped. The population size is simply the number of parameter combinations that will be attempted at each generation. It's kind of a balance that you will need to explore for your particular problem - e.g. It might be more computationally efficient to reduce the number of the population, but extend the maximum number of generations. Also, I found that increasing the mutation rate and elitism setting found the solution faster (e.g. `pmutation = 0.2, elitism = popSize*0.2`). The best correlation I found in several runs was `0.9723283`.

Comment: See my edited answer regarding how to solve for the lowest correlation.

Comment: Let's make it more generalized. What if we have to sample such that correlation between A and B is close to some value C (say C = -0.1).

Comment: OK, last edit from me - I adjusted the second example, which now aims at a particular correlation value defined by `targ`. For the -0.1 target, this resulted in a combination of datapoints that resulted in `r = -0.0998439`.

Comment: Perfect! The solution is more generalized now and so will help users broadly.